# Integrating AngularJS and DagreD3 - AngularJS directive does not update on model change.

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

I am writing and AngularJS directive for [DagreD3](https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre-d3). I have some problems with $scope update in Angular. When I update the Model, the Directive does not re-render the graph.

[A plunker can be found here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/y42fgYL73BtulQ3qlT7Q?p=preview)

My directive looks like this:

```
myApp.directive('acDagre', function() {

function link(scope, element, attrs) {

  scope.$watch(scope.graph, function(value) {
    alert('update'); //NOT EVEN THIS IS CALLED ON UPDATE
  });

  var renderer = new dagreD3.Renderer();
  renderer.run(scope.graph, d3.select("svg g"));
}
return {
  restrict: "A",
  link: link
};
```

The variable $scope.graph is modified in the Controller during runtime like this:

```
$scope.addNode = function(){
 $scope.graph.addNode("kbacon2", { label: "Kevin Bacon the second" });
}
```

Did I understand something wrong in Angular? Everytime the Variable $scope.graph is changed, i want the graph to update. 
You can find more information in the Plunker.

Thank you for very much your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The watcher should look either like this:

```
scope.$watch('graph', function(value) {
  console.log('update');
});
```

Or like this:

```
scope.$watch(function () { return scope.graph; }, function(value) {
  console.log('update');
});
```

It will not fire when adding nodes however, cause it's comparing by reference.

You can add `true` as a third parameter to perform a deep watch instead (it will use `angular.equals`):

```
scope.$watch('graph', function(value) {
  console.log('update');
}, true);
```

Note that this is more expensive.

Example:

```
.directive('acDagre', function() {

  var renderer = new dagreD3.Renderer();

  function link(scope, element, attrs) {

    scope.$watch(function () { return scope.graph; }, function(value) {
      render();
    }, true);

    var render = function() {
      renderer.run(scope.graph, d3.select("svg g"));
    };
  }

  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: link
  };
});
```

**Demo**: http://plnkr.co/edit/Dn1t3sMH58mDz9HhqYD5?p=preview

If you are just changing the nodes you can define the `watchExpression` like this instead:

```
scope.$watch(function () { return scope.graph._nodes; }
```

Deep watching large objects can have a negative effect on performance. This will of course depend on the size and complexity of the watched object and the application, but it's good to be aware of.